# Mapstruct : generated sources in intelliJ using annotationProcessorPaths

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, annotation-processing, mapstruct

I used `Eclipse` IDE to develop an application that uses `Mapstruct` and I'm moving now to `IntelliJ` to continue the development.

Everything worked fine on Eclipse but I have an unexpected behavior on IntelliJ due to the usage of `annotationProcessorPaths`.

My configuration is as below :

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
    <annotationProcessorPaths>
        <path>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
        </path>
    </annotationProcessorPaths>
    <source>${java.version}</source>
    <target>${java.version}</target>
    <compilerArgs>
        <compilerArg>
            -Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=${mapstruct.defaultComponentModel}
        </compilerArg>
        <compilerArg>
            -Aorg.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor
        </compilerArg>
    </compilerArgs>
</configuration>
```

On IntelliJ, When I launch a Maven clean install I get the generated source :

```
@Component

public class FieldMapperImpl implements FieldMapper {

    @Autowired

    private FieldMapperResolver fieldMapperResolver;

...
}
```

But when I run/debug my Spring Boot app, the generated source I get is :

```
public class FieldMapperImpl implements FieldMapper {

    private final FieldMapperResolver fieldMapperResolver = new FieldMapperResolver();
    ...
    }
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Looks like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-150621.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume that you are running/debugging the Spring Boot app via IntelliJ directly. The reason why that is happening is because IntelliJ does not pick up the configuration from the `maven-compiler-plugin`. See [IDEA-143742](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-143742) and [IDEA-150621](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-150621).

You will also have to configure the IntelliJ Annotation Processor Options separately. You can find that in Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Annotation Processors

It is strange how IntelliJ even invokes the processor, do you have the `mapstruct-processor` also as a dependency in your pom?

Edit: 
IntelliJ does not pick up the maven-compiler-plugin compiler arguments. The default component model is set via the annotation processor options. In order for IntelliJ to correctly work one should either set the same property in the IntelliJ configuration or use `@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")`. More info in the [documentation](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#using-dependency-injection)

Comment: Yes I have it. I tried with a `<optional>true</optional>` and a `<scope>provided</scope>`. But it does not solve the problem.

Comment: That is because IntelliJ is not configured with the `mapstruct.defaultComponentModel`. In the maven-compiler-plugin you have that most probably as spring, and when IntelliJ runs it does not use that property, it uses default so MapStruct generates the MapperReferences without `@Autowired`. You either need to set that in the IntelliJ config or on `@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")` or via `@MapperConfig(componentModel = "spring")` and use that in the `@Mapper`

Comment: Is there any way to tell IntelliJ to pass this argument while processing the annotation ?

Comment: Yes you can. I have already written a way in the answer.

>You will also have to configure the IntelliJ Annotation Processor Options separately. You can find that in Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Annotation Processors

Comment: You are right, I will test it. Thank you very much.

Comment: There are two ways to "configure" the processor.  One way is to "obtain Processors from Project Classpath" which does not seem to work.  The other way is to set the Processor path.  What do we point to?